# Many CGContext invalid context 0x0 errors iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, cgcontext

My app has suddenly started generating a lot of errors of this type:

```
<Error>: CGContextSetInterpolationQuality: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. 
This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing  
to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please  
fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
```

and so on for CGContextDrawImage, CGBitmapContextCreateImage, etc.

I'm clearly doing something seriously wrong but I'm not sure what. I'm using the code below which I adapted from someone else for my app. It basically resizes an image taking into account the device.

The code seems to work fine and my app does what is expected but I'm not sure what's causing the errors which seem quite serious. Can anyone see anything obvious in my code that might be causing these errors?

```
-(UIImage *)resizeImage:(NSString *)imageName {

    UIImage *originalImage = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    CGRect newRect = CGRectIntegral(CGRectMake(0, 0, originalImage.size.width * myScalingFactor, originalImage.size.height * myScalingFactor));
    CGImageRef imageRef = originalImage.CGImage;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    CGContextRef bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(
                                                NULL,
                                                newRect.size.width,
                                                newRect.size.height,
                                                8,
                                                (newRect.size.width * 4),
                                                colorSpace,
                                                kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast
                                                );

    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(bitmap, 3);
    CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, newRect, imageRef);
    CGImageRef newImageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmap);
    UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImageRef];
    CGContextRelease(bitmap);
    CGImageRelease(newImageRef);

    return newImage;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`CGContextSetInterpolationQuality: invalid context 0x0.` means that the `context` parameter passed to `CGContextSetInterpolationQuality` was a null pointer (hence the memory address 0x0).

To avoid this, you should check if `CGBitmapContextCreate` returns `NULL`. This can happen if you supply a invalid width/height (either being zero).

Comment: Perfect, that was the problem. I was loading an image that didn't exist and passing thus a value of 0 to the context. Thanks very much for the answer.

Comment: I'm getting this error in this case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592073/speed-up-saving-image-ios

Answer (score -2):

**Edit. Aug 2017**
This is probably useless advice. I'm not deleting it for the sake of posterity. I can't remember the circumstances that this occurred, so it's barely of value.

---

This is an error that I have just learnt to ignore.
It's quite difficult to take serious when even iOS suffers from this error a lot. If you connect your device to your Mac and look at the debug console, you will see that Springboard logs these errors all the time too. In the screenshot below I was simply changing the screen brightness, which sent the device console into overdrive.
[image]

Unfortunately when debugging this clutters the console, but according to [this](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/13683) thread, it is a problem with iOS and can be ignored.

**Edit**
I'm not sure why I keep getting downvoted for this response. I cited my source, which shows Apple staff clearly acknowledging that it is an issue with the OS. If anyone else feels the need to downvote, please tell me where I went wrong. Cheers like.[image]

Comment: The reason you keep getting downvoted is your phrase "This is an error that I have just learnt to ignore.". A software developer can not learn to ignore errors.

Comment: @fotisgpap well, considering it was a known OS bug, there's not much I could do about it. I don't tend to ignore bugs, however when it's out my hands and Apple engineers tell me to ignore it, I do exactly that. As dissatisfying as it was, I did as such. I can't exactly decompile iOS and deploy it, can I? I quite clearly didn't ignore it at first, which is why I found this post and the Apple forum question, amongst others.

Comment: but as you can see from the answer above, there are certain cases that the error is caused by the developer. If everyone follows your advice to ignore this error because in some cases it's an ios bug, people will not find a solution for the case it is a developer bug. It would be nice to rephrase it. You could say that in your case (describe your case) it's an ios bug and you can ignore it.